# How to exclude all rows with same id if one column is not null

Tags: mysql, sql

my following query :

```
select oh.id_order,pc.id_product_comment,od.product_id
from `ps_order_history` oh
INNER JOIN `ps_orders` o ON o.id_order = oh.id_order
INNER JOIN `ps_order_detail` od ON od.id_order = oh.id_order
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_comment` pc ON pc.`id_customer` = o.`id_customer` AND pc.`id_product` = od.`product_id`
where oh.`id_order_state` = 2
AND (oh.date_add < pc.date_add OR pc.date_add IS NULL)
```

return the following result :

```
id_order  |  id_product_comment  |  product_id
----------------------------------------------
  6              3                 6
  6             NULL               5
  5             NULL               6
  5             NULL               5
```

I want to exclude rows with id_order 6 because one row has a id_product_comment not null.
Any ideas ?

Comment: You mean you want to exclude id_order 5 as it has both NULL values in id_product_comment?

Comment: sorry i want to exclude id_order 6, i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

ok the solution :

```
    select oh.id_order,pc.id_product_comment,od.product_id
from `ps_order_history` oh
INNER JOIN `ps_orders` o ON o.id_order = oh.id_order
INNER JOIN `ps_order_detail` od ON od.id_order = oh.id_order
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_comment` pc ON pc.`id_customer` = o.`id_customer` AND pc.`id_product` = od.`product_id`
where oh.`id_order_state` = 2
AND (oh.date_add < pc.date_add OR pc.date_add IS NULL)
GROUP BY oh.id_order
HAVING pc.id_product_comment IS NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a solution that will consistently work.  You GROUP BY oh.id_order, so will only return 1 row per id_order. In your sample data you will just return 1 of the 2 rows for id_order of 5; which product_id will be in that row is not defined. Further you then check for _HAVING pc.id_product_comment IS NULL_ , but you have no control over which rows value of pc.id_product_comment is returned to check for NULL, so you may or may not get id_order of 6 excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a sub query. the sub query gets a list of the id_order which have any entries on ps_product_comment. This is left joined to the main query and then the WHERE clause checks that there was not matching record.

```
SELECT oh.id_order,
        pc.id_product_comment,
        od.product_id
FROM `ps_order_history` oh
INNER JOIN `ps_orders` o ON o.id_order = oh.id_order
INNER JOIN `ps_order_detail` od ON od.id_order = oh.id_order
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ps_product_comment` pc ON pc.`id_customer` = o.`id_customer` AND pc.`id_product` = od.`product_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT o.id_order
    FROM ps_orders` o 
    INNER JOIN `ps_order_detail` od ON od.id_order = o.id_order
    INNER JOIN `ps_product_comment` pc ON pc.`id_customer` = o.`id_customer` AND pc.`id_product` = od.`product_id`
) sub0
ON sub0.id_order = oh.id_order
WHERE oh.`id_order_state` = 2
AND (oh.date_add < pc.date_add 
OR pc.date_add IS NULL)
AND sub0.id_order IS NULL
```